# cnn_utils module missing from Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a copy of a notebook from my Coursera class (which is in Jupyter) in Colab and getting an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1ee14f68a167> in <module>()
      8 import tensorflow as tf
      9 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
---> 10 from cnn_utils import *
     11 
     12 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cnn_utils'
```

i tried doing `!pip install` but it yelled at me again:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cnn_utils (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cnn_utils
```

anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cnn_utils` here is just a personal library for the course, not a public module. You cannot install it with `pip install`.

You need to find the source of `cnn_utils.py` then download that to your computer, then upload it to Colab.

Answer (score 0):

here is the [cnn_utils.py](https://github.com/JudasDie/deeplearning.ai/blob/master/Convolutional%20Neural%20Networks/week1/cnn_utils.py) from coursera course